# OpenAPI - specify multipart within a multipart with "boundary" in the Content-Type

Tags: openapi, multipart, mulesoft

I have an API which accepts multipart/form-data as the request body, where the second part is itself multipart/mixed, and I need to specify it with OpenAPI (v3).

I tried to specify it as follows (the "second part" is the one called "data"):

```
requestBody:
    content:
      multipart/form-data:
        schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            metadata:
              [...]
            data:
              type: object
              format: multipart/mixed
        encoding:
          metadata:
            [...]
          data:
            contentType: multipart/mixed
```

But then it would expect the second part's Content-Type to be exactly `"multipart/mixed"`, and the actual incoming Content-Type value would be `"multipart/mixed; boundary=..."`, and it would reject such payloads due to the extra characters `; boundary=...`.

So I tried to change data's contentType to `multipart/*`:

```
              data:
                contentType: multipart/*
```

But when I test it, it expects the Content-Type to be the regular string `"multipart/*"` rather than an actual wildcard.

How can I declare the second part to be multipart/mixed while allowing for the trailing `; boundary=...` in the Content-Type?

Comment: Please provide details of the actual implementation. What products and versions are you using to implement the API? Provide some snippets of the actual code/configurations (text only). Add error messages with details from the log (text only).

Comment: MuleSoft is not a product. It is a company name, that provides many products that could be related to this issue. You need to mention specific products/technologies. Please update the question to add the details from your comment and also the Mule runtime version (APIKit only works on Mule applications deployed on a Mule runtime). Usually it is useful to add more details from the log rather than just the one line error message. Is there more detail to add? Have you tried with the latest APIKit version?